# Why am i not able to see the blocks im placing? (Ursina)

Tags: python, ursina

Im trying to make an sandbox game where you can place blocks but the texture for the Block does not appear and neither does the block. Before i added the second def add_box_wood it all worked just fine.

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

app = Ursina()
player = FirstPersonController()
Sky()

boxes = []

def add_box(position):
    boxes.append(
        Button(
        parent=scene,
        model="cube",
        origin=0.5,
        color="green",
        position=position,
        texture="grass"
      )
    )

def add_box_wood(position):
    boxes.append(
        Button(
        parent=scene,
        model="cube",
        origin=0.5,
        color="brown",
        position=position,
        texture='texture/wood.jpg'
      )
    )

for x in range(20):
  for y in range(20):
    add_box( (x, -4, y) )

def input(key):
    for box in boxes:
        if box.hovered:
            if key == "right mouse down":
                add_box_wood(box.position + mouse.normal)
            if key == "left mouse down":
                boxes.remove(box)
                destroy(box)


app.run()
```

I tried to just color it brown but that didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed few issues:

- Wood texture is missing. You need to add `wood.png` image to the script folder
- You also removing grass by mouse click. Need to add additional condition to check that you're removing only wood
- You're using wildcard import: `from ursina import *`. It's a bad practice

Here is the fixed code:

```
import ursina
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

app = ursina.Ursina()
player = FirstPersonController()
ursina.Sky()
boxes = []
for x in range(20):
    for y in range(20):
        boxes.append(ursina.Button(parent=ursina.scene, model='cube', origin=0.5, color='green', position=(x, -4, y), texture='grass'))


def input(key):
    for box in boxes:
        if box.hovered:
            if key == 'right mouse down':
                boxes.append(ursina.Button(parent=ursina.scene, model='cube', origin=0.5, color='brown', position=box.position+ursina.mouse.normal, texture='wood'))
            elif key == 'left mouse down' and box.texture.name == 'wood.png':
                boxes.remove(box)
                ursina.destroy(box)


app.run()
```

Output:

[image: ursina]